# Google Search Console and Magento Multistore

Tags: magento2, google, google-tag-manager

I have a multistore set up with an english **domain.com/en_ca** and french store **domain.com/fr_ca**, **fr_ca** and **en_ca** are added by Magento, by enabling the configuration Add Store Code to **Urls to Yes**.

My problem is to **configure google sitemap** for each domain.

I cannot use **domain.com/en_ca/sitemap_en.xml**, **sitemap_en.xml** is on the root directory, and google force me to use **domain.com/en_ca, domain.com/en_ca/sitemap_en.xml** return a **404 page error**.

I created a real directory **en_ca** on the root and put the sitemap on it, but this cause the **website to stop working**.

Any one have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using magento2 then you might to create your sitemap in **pub** folder
for example

```
domain.com/en_ca/sitemap_en.xml
domain.com/fr_ca/sitemap_fr.xml
```

Comment: I created a real directory en_ca on the root and put the sitemap on it, but this cause the website to stop working.

Comment: if i am not wrong you want to setup multi store and create sitemaps for these... right? Magento itself has own multi store functionality so you no need to create such folders on root, you can manage from magento admin panel.

Comment: i tried to put the sitemap in /pub/static/frontend/Vendor/cus-theme/fr_CA but i always get 404 error

Comment: put sitemap directly in /pub/ folder

Comment: i created redirects in htacccess